# Forming a line from two points

Tags: coordinate-systems

In the book Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision, it says "a line is defined by the join of two points" in section [3.2.2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=si3R3Pfa98QC&lpg=PA69&ots=aRtXkx8b3O&dq=join%20of%20two%20points&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Later on it goes to say there is a point $P^+x$ (the point that projects to x on the image plane) and $C$ (the camera centre). And that the lined formed is the join of these two points (equation 6.13 in the book, page 162):

$$X(\lambda) = P^+x + \lambda C$$

How does adding the two create a line?

If you have a two point in cartesian coordinates say $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, then $\mu \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + \lambda \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ does not form a line between those two points.

Comment: A line can be expressed in a form $r(\lambda)=a+b\lambda$ where $r,a$ are position vectors of general point of line, and $a$ a point on the line, and $b$ is a gradient vector of the line (Here $\lambda$ is a (real) parameter)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter $\lambda$ runs through the set of real numbers. Every value of $\lambda$ defines a point on the line.

Please note that the book you are quoting does not seem to use Cartesian coordinates but projective coordinates. A point in projective 3-space is represented by a column of *four* numbers, not all of them 0, and two such columns represent the same point if and only if the columns are multiples of each other.

In such a coordinate system, the line joining two points can indeed be expressed by linear combinations with two real parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu.$